# Clean uninstall utillity on Linux Manjaro

Tags: linux, package, uninstallation, manjaro

Uninstalling a program still leaves some trashes behind, such as cache and config files.
Remaining config files are especially annoying when I'm re-installing.
So on Windows, I often use IObit uninstaller to remove all of those at once.
Is their a utility for this "Clean Uninstalling" in Manjaro Linux? (or just Linux generally)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using Manjaro Linux, which is based on Arch Linux, I will tell you the solution for Arch based distros.

To unisntall a program properly, use the command below:

```
sudo pacman -Rns <packagename>
```

`-R` - is the actual removal option

`n` - is for removing backup configuration files saved by `pacman`

`s` - is for removing the dependencies of the given package which are not required by other packages

`pacman` does not remove configuration files, etc. created by the package.

---

All credits for the solution goes to the user [ibnarrashid](https://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/by/ibnarrashid) who posted [their solution](https://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/8141/archlinux-remove-a-package-completely-from-the-system.) on [commandlinefu.com](http://commandlinefu.com)